# getmail is not configured with imap and pop server

Tags: imap, pop3

Today i am setup getmail to retrieve emails with exim4 for sending mails on my linode vps server. In configuration [getmailrc] file, i am using imap server with port number 143 shown below:

[retriever]
type = SimpleIMAPRetriever
server = mail.appmailz.com
port = 143

in command prompt, using getmail to retrieve mails but it shows error below:

2012-06-21 11:13:59 getmailOperationError error (socket error during connect ([Errno -2] Name or service not known))
2012-06-21 11:14:49 getmailOperationError error (IMAP error (Login failed.))
2012-06-21 11:17:56 getmailOperationError error (IMAP error (Login failed.))

I am noob for this configuration, please help me.